# Some Laravel 4 PSR-0 issues?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have noticed that Laravel 4 is using some of the [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/) standards. I have recently installed the SensioLabs tool php-cs-fixer that detects and fixes most of the issues when we want to follow the PHP Coding Standards.

I have execute the command in my bare Laravel 4 copy and this is the log.

```
php-cs-fixer fix app/
! Class User in /home/javier/Code/laravel/app/models/User.php should have at least a vendor namespace according to PSR-0 rules
! Class DatabaseSeeder in /home/javier/Code/laravel/app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php should have at least a vendor namespace according to PSR-0 rules
! Class HomeController in /home/javier/Code/laravel/app/controllers/HomeController.php should have at least a vendor namespace according to PSR-0 rules
! Class BaseController in /home/javier/Code/laravel/app/controllers/BaseController.php should have at least a vendor namespace according to PSR-0 rules
```

The output shows some issues related to the Autoloading Standard PSR-0.
What's going on here ??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Consider that, altough far, Laravel 4 is still in the testing phase. I suggest you report the issue on their tracker, or on the laravel forum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reporting the *issue* on the github laravel tracker i get a great response courtesy of [@javiervd](https://github.com/javiervd).

Here is the answer

> The problem is that the classes inside the "app" folder do not follow PSR-0, that's why the composer autoloader uses classmap instead of PSR-0.
>
> To quote @daylerees
>
> > Now you may be asking yourself, why doesn't Laravel set this by default?
> >
> > Well Laravel doesn't know what your project is called, and what the root namespace would be. It is a zero configuration framework, meaning it should 'just work' out of the box. Class mapping is then the most sensible choice.

It makes a lot of sense.